# How to perform an elementwise maximum of two columns in a Python polars expression?

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

How can I calculate the elementwise maximum of two columns in Polars inside an expression?

Polars version = 0.13.31

Problem statement as code:

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": np.arange(5),
    "b": np.arange(5)[::-1]
})
# Produce a column with the values [4, 3, 2, 3, 4] using df.select([ ... ]).alias("max(a, b)")
```

#### Things I've tried

Polars claims to support numpy universal functions ([docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/numpy.html?highlight=ufunc#numpy-interop)), which includes np.maximum which does what I'm asking for. However when I try that I get an error.

```
df.select([
    np.maximum(pl.col("a"), pl.col("b")).alias("max(a, b)")
])
# TypeError: maximum() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 1 were given
```

There appears to be no Polars builtin for this, there is `pl.max` but this returns only the single maximum element in an array.

Using `.map()`

```
my_df.select([
    pl.col(["a", "b"]).map(np.maximum)
])
# PanicException
```

#### Current workaround

I'm able to do this using the following snippet however I want to be able to do this inside an expresion as it's much more convenient.

```
df["max(a, b)"] = np.maximum(df["a"], df["b"])
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`.max_horizontal()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.max_horizontal.html)

```py
df = pl.select(
   a = pl.int_range(0, 5),
   b = pl.int_range(0, 5).reverse(),
)
```

```
shape: (5, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 4   │
│ 1   ┆ 3   │
│ 2   ┆ 2   │
│ 3   ┆ 1   │
│ 4   ┆ 0   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

```py
df.with_columns(
   pl.max_horizontal('a', 'b').alias('max(a, b)')
)
```

```
shape: (5, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬───────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ max(a, b) │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64       │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════════╡
│ 0   ┆ 4   ┆ 4         │
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 3         │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 2         │
│ 3   ┆ 1   ┆ 3         │
│ 4   ┆ 0   ┆ 4         │
└─────┴─────┴───────────┘
```

The list of [dedicated horizontal functions.](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/search.html?q=_horizontal)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is definitely my bad for not reading the docs thoroughly enough.

Answer (score 1):

As of now (Oct, 2023) `max` should be replaced with `max_horizontal`, without the use of `pl.col`, and `with_column` should be `with_columns`:

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": np.arange(5),
    "b": np.arange(5)[::-1]
})

df.with_columns(
    pl.max_horizontal(['a', 'b']).alias('max(a, b)')
)
```